# iOS: change subview with segmented control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, subview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have four subview and when I select (segment ==1) in segmented control other view must have alpha at 0.00 and only subview number 1 must have alpha at 1.00, I show my code:

```
if (segmentedContr.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    [subView1 setAlpha:0.0];

      }
```

it's simple, but where I must write this code? In an IBAction? or in a generic method (void)? If I do

```
-(void)segmentAction:(id)sender
```

where I must call this method?

Comment: `IBAction` is translated by the preprocessor to `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't have to call that method explicitly from anywhere.**

That method will be called automatically *when you select a segment* in the segmented control. And, make sure you have set the *target* and *action* for the segmented control.

```
[segmentedContr addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: can you write an example of delegate property?

Comment: and where I must write it? in viewdidload?

Comment: there is an error; it say that property delegate not found on object of type UISegmented Control

Comment: @blackguardian: Sorry. I made a mistake. Actually you won't set delegate for segmented controls. You have to use `[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: @blackguardian: Great. Please delete the above comments if possible.